# How to use USPS and UPS PHP API for getting tracking Information

Tags: magento-1.7, shipping

I want to find the shipping dates from USPS and UPS, How do I find it. Is there any API so I can pas a tracking number and returns me these details.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both USPS and UPS have an API you can use to access this information. I suggest reviewing their technical docs on how to implement these features.

https://www.usps.com/business/web-tools-apis/track-and-confirm-v1-3a.htm
https://www.ups.com/upsdeveloperkit/downloadresource?loc=en_US